# How to access object's properties when looping through an array of objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, object

```
class LineAnalyzer
  @@highest_wf_count = 0
  @@highest_wf_words = Array.new

  def highest_wf_count
    @@highest_wf_count
  end

  def higest_wf_words
    @@highest_wf_words
  end

  attr_accessor :linesCount, :content , :line_number
  @content
  @line_number

  def initialize(line,line_count)
    @content = line
    @line_number = line_count
    #* call the calculate_word_frequency() method.
    calculate_word_frequency()
  end

  def calculate_word_frequency()
     @@count = Hash.new(0)
     @content.split.each do |word|
      @@count[word.downcase] += 1
     end

     @@count.each_pair do |key, value| 
       if value > @@highest_wf_count 
         @@highest_wf_count = value
       end
     end

     @@count.each_pair do |key, value| 
       if value == @@highest_wf_count 
        @@highest_wf_words << key
       end
     end    
  end
end

#  Implement a class called Solution. 
class Solution 
    attr_accessor :highest_count_across_lines, :highest_count_words_across_lines
    @highest_count_across_lines = 0
    @highest_count_words_across_lines = Array.new()
    @@LineAnalyzers = Array.new

    def analyze_file
      line_count = 1
      x = File.foreach('C:\x\test.txt')
      x.each{ |line|
        @@LineAnalyzers << LineAnalyzer.new(line , line_count)
        line_count+=1
      } 
      puts @@LineAnalyzers.inspect
    end

    def calculate_line_with_highest_frequency
      @@LineAnalyzers.map { |line|
        #Here is the problem.... I need to assign values to @highest_counts_across_lines and @highest_count_words_across_lines
      }
    end 
end
```

My question here is that I have this LineAnalyzers array and I have the highest_wf_count and highest_wf_words and I want to assign them to @higest_count_across_lines and @highest_count_accross_words, and I don't know how to access the LineAnalyzer properties when looping in solution class

Comment: You are using to much class variables (with double @@) . some of them are just wrong. You should always use instance variables, and only if there is a really good reason, use a class variable.

Comment: well some things don't work otherwise

Comment: It is a sign that your design is wrong. Which object should have which resposibilities?

Comment: @Meier: well, there's no inheritance here so @@vars are pretty much the same as class instance vars, only more convenient (same syntax to access them from both instance and class levels). And I agree, these vars are to be avoided.

Comment: @Yolanda: the problem is not clear. You want to assign data from where to where?

Comment: I have a feeling that this whole script can be replaced with 5 lines or less.

Comment: @Sergio well i know I did it all in a few lines , but this is a homework that I should put in like this in two classes.

Comment: @Sergio well as I am looping through the LineAnalyzers array which is an array of LineAnalyzer object, I want to set solution class values (highest_count_accross_lines and highest_count_across_words with values from lineAnalyzers[0].highest_wf_count and lineAnalyzers[0].highest_wf_words and so on...)

Comment: I just cannot write line.highest_wf_count or line.highest_wf_words

Comment: @Yolanda: why you can't? Looking at the code, you should be able to.

Comment: yes but i don't know how

Comment: I am a newbie to Ruby

Comment: yes, you can. line is in reality a lineAnalyser object. but there are other errors. for example, you overwrite class variables each time with new.

Comment: @Meier Can you please rewrite the code to demonstrate that to me please

Comment: that why you need to think what the purpose of each object is. than you can think, what instance variables are needed.

Comment: Than I do your homework :)

Comment: Just out of curiousity, can you show your compact solution (the one without classes and in under 10 lines)?

Comment: I would rename lineAnalyser to Analyser. it is reponsible for all analysing, but it not responsible to do file input/output. Give it a method analyseLine(line) this adds to the instance variable with a hash of all words. no class variables needed.

Comment: @Meier I am not asking you to do my homework I am just asking how i can write line.highest_wf_count without getting errors.

Comment: @Sergio here is the code without using classes code without using classes :   word_frequency = Hash.new(0)
    content = File.foreach('C:\assignment-Calc-Max-Word-Freq\test.txt')
    content.each{|line|
        line.split.each do |word|
           word_frequency[word.downcase]+=1
        end
      } 
word_frequency.each_pair do |key, value| 
  puts "Key: #{key} value: #{value}" 
end
  max =0 
word_frequency.each_pair do |key, value|  
  if value > max 
   max = value
  end
end
hfwords = Array.new(0)
word_frequency.each_pair do |key, value| 
  if value == max 
   hfwords << key
  end
end

Comment: "without getting errors" - why is it that we only hear about you getting any errors on the second page of comments?

Comment: If you posted an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you would have gotten an answer in _minutes_ (sometimes even seconds).

Comment: thank you Sergio I will look that up now part of the issue is solved.... line.highest_wf_count worked fine but the issue is with line.highest_wf_words as I get "block with calculate_line_with_highest_frequency", : undefined method highest_wf_words for LineAnalyzer...

Comment: BTW, this is your script in 5 lines: http://pastie.org/10445014

Comment: @Yolanda: typo in your code: `def higest_wf_words`.

Comment: Outch, thanks for finding that typoe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a short answer solved by    Sergio Tulentsev

```
word_freq = File.new(filename, 'r').each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |line, memo|
line.split.each {|word| memo[word] += 1 }
end

max = word_freq.values.max
most_frequent_words = word_freq.select {|k, v| v == max }.map[0]
```